# android check boxes

Tags: android, checkbox

I need an xml file for the following: I have a check box button. When I click it 3 more check boxes buttons will apprear on the screen. How to do that ?

Comment: [SO] is not "teach me how to program " site .. please read the rules detailed in [faq], thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add all the checkboxes to the layout, so they are all visible, and then use code like this to make some visible/invisible dynamically:

```
findViewById(R.id.checkbox5).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

findViewById(R.id.checkbox5).setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

You can set the default visibility using `android:visibility="gone"` in the XML

Comment: thx for reply. How to change the dimensions of the 3 children check boxes smaller than the parent?

Comment: Best to post new questions for further issues. UI Views in Android are done with bitmaps, some stretch but some will not. You can try using layout_height and layout_width to set the size, but I expect that with checkboxes it will not work (as it does for a TextView), and you will need to provide your own (smaller) image set, using a drawable <selector> (to specify which image to use for selected, and unselected)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you do it. You could add the three extra check boxes in your layout file and then set them invisible until the right check box is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can make gone to visible your new checkboxes.

or

You can inflate new checkboxes and add to the desired layout.

like below is the code to add multiple images

```
p

rivate LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                            circleLinearLayout.removeAllViews();

                while (circlesNeedToDisplay > 0) {
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(
                            R.layout.circle_item, null);
                    circleLinearLayout.addView(imageView);
                    circles.add(imageView);
                    circlesNeedToDisplay--;
                }
```

---

xml code for **R.layout.circle_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

By using the same procedure you can add check boxes as well.